# weird structure declaration method in C

Tags: c, struct

This is from the header file for the library functions of CSR8670 Bluetooth chip

```
typedef struct TaskData { void (*handler)(Task, MessageId, Message); } TaskData;
```

**What kind of structure declaration is this?** What are the member data for this structure?
Here is the full header file for context:

```
/* This file was automatically generated from syscalls.in 17.2 */

#ifndef __MESSAGE__H

#define __MESSAGE__H

#include <csrtypes.h>
/*! @file message_.h @brief Message types */
/*!
Message identifier type.
*/
typedef uint16 MessageId;
/*!
Message delay type.
*/
typedef uint32 Delay;
/*!
Message type.
*/
typedef const void *Message;
/*!
Task type.
*/
typedef struct TaskData *Task;
/*!
TaskData type.
*/
typedef struct TaskData { void (*handler)(Task, MessageId, Message); } TaskData;

#endif
```

I am still not sure what *handler means. I have not been able to find any other references to handler in the other header file. If it's relevant, Task represents a sort of routine running on the firmware that accepts and processes the message that the firmware may receive from external sources (for example, a bluetooth device trying to connect to the CSR board).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct TaskData { void (*handler)(Task, MessageId, Message); } TaskData;
```

The only member of this structure is:

```
void (*handler)(Task, MessageId, Message);
```

i.e a function pointer named `handler` which can point to a function which returns `void` & takes arguments of type `Task`, `MessageId`, and `Message`

This can be accessed for example like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  void (*hand)(int a);
} str;

void func(int a)
{
  printf("Value of a = %d\n", a);
}

int main ()
{
  str var;

  var.hand = func;
  var.hand(25);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes it is... "hand" is the structure member in this case. in your example it is "handler". we are accessing the member named "hand". hope it is clear... u can google for function pointers in c.

Answer (score 2):

The `struct TaskData` has only member which is a function pointer and it is

```
void (*handler)(Task, MessageId, Message);
```

Comment: could you please give me a sample of how whatever the member of this structure is, could be accessed?

Comment: @user13267 Please `google` for function pointers and learn about it. They are similar to pointers and since pointer is a data-type they can be member of a structure

Answer (score 2):

`handler` is a pointer to a *function* that returns `void` and has parameters with types `Task`, `MessageId`, and `Message` in that order.

`TaskData` is a structure containing that one member.

It's probably used by some library function to call a function that the *user* of that library has to define. (These are known as *callback* functions and are idiomatic in C.)

Comment: could you please give me a sample of how whatever the member of this structure is, could be accessed?

Answer (score 1):

```
void (*handler)(Task, MessageId, Message);
```

This is a function pointer, which is the only member of the structure `struct TaskData`.

The function pointer is a pointer to a function which should have

- Return type as `void`.
- Three input parameter of type `Task`, `MessageId`, `Message`, respectively, which are again some `typedef`s.

---

EDIT:

*Usage*

as Mentioned in the comment below, for a variable `TaskData task;` the access should be [in pseudocode]

```
// void somefunc(Task t, MessageId mid, Message m) is the function
task.handler = somefunc;
```

and

```
Task p;
MessageId q;
Message r;

task.handler(p,q,r);   
//function somefunc() will be called with argument p, q,and r
```

Comment: So supposing I make a variable of the type TaskData as TaskData            task;. How would I access it's member?

Comment: @user13267 you can use the structure reference [`.`] or structure dereference [`->`] operator to access a structure manber. in your case, it should be `.` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Any thing inside a structure is its member. `handler` is a function pointer to a function which accepts three arguments of types `Task, MessageId, Message` and returns `void`. This is a member of structure.

The main use of function pointers in structure is used to get the object oriented feature of Polymorphism (virtual function) in C.